# express + ejs login widget

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am  trying to make easy widget for buttons login/logout.

laout.ejs

```
  <% include ../shared/login_logout %>
```

login_logout.ejs

`<% if ( !common.IsDefined(membershipHelper.GetCurrentUser(request , response)) ) { %>`

`<li class="pull-right"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>`

`<% } else { %>`

`<li class="pull-right"><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>`

`<% } %>`

membershipHelper.GetCurrentUser - this method checks request session for user_id and if it finds it returns user if it is found in db(mongoDB) else it returns null. As user is returned in callback function of User.findById ejs file receives "undefined" always. I thought to put this GetCurrentUser in the middleware but it look like I can't set null or undefined to locals variable

What can be solution for this problem?

Comment: so any one, how do you people work with current user and such login/logout widjets???